# PTIJ: Loshon hara by kiddush

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בקֶר יום הַשִּׁשִּׁי. וַיְכֻלּוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם
> וְהָאָרֶץ וְכָל צְבָאָם וַיְכַל אֱלהִים בַּיּום הַשְּׁבִיעִי
> מְלַאכְתּו אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה. וַיִּשְׁבּת בַּיּום הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִכָּל
> מְלַאכְתּו אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה וַיְבָרֶךְ אֱלהִים אֶת יום הַשְּׁבִיעִי
> וַיְקַדֵּשׁ אתו. כִּי בו שָׁבַת מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּו אֲשֶׁר בָּרָא
> אֱלהִים לַעֲשׂות
>
> **סַבְרִי מָרָנָן**
>
> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה
> אַדָנָי אֱלהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעולָם בּורֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן

With all the laws we have about *loshon hara, loshon naki, derech eretz, and bein adam l'chaveiro*, what is the excuse for addressing one's tablemates as "morons" at the beginning of kiddush?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This is especially confusing, as in the early 20th Century "moron" referred to an adult with a mental capactiy of a 8-12 year old child. Only those who are over bar mitzvah can join in a zimmun.

Comment: Is adult the slurred form of a-dolt?

Comment: This is similar to congregations calling the chazzan a blessed idiot during davening. Baruch schmo.

Comment: Gotta admit ... this is one of the most moronic PTIJ questions I have ever seen.

Comment: Now that I have a bit more time to re-read your question, I have to add that one of the more moronic things about this question is that you had to include the entire first paragraph when all you're really asking about are the last two lines! But, all is not lost. You can redeem some of your moronism by editing the question.

Comment: @DanF I really wanted to work "Savri, morons" in there but this was the closest I could come

Answer (score 4):

The laws of proper speech are relaxed during the kiddush. The ancient piyut [*An'im Zemorot*](https://www.scribd.com/doc/50931547/2011-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA), by [Eli Schorr](http://purim365.blogspot.co.il/), addresses precisely our case:

> מִדֵּי דַּבְּרִי בְּלָשׁוֹן וָלֶסֶת, אֲנָשִׁים יוֹצְאִים מִבֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת
>
> עַל כֵּן אֲדַבֵּר בְּסִיּוּם הַתְּפִלָּה, דִּבְרֵי רְכִילוּת וְשִֹיחָה בְּטֵלָה
>
> Lo, I speak, with tongue and jaw,
>
> Congregants, from the sanctuary, withdraw,
>
> Therefore I shall speak, following worship,
>
> Words of idle chatter and gossip.

Answer (score 1):

SAH, please excuse a personal "bias" in answering this question, in the spirit of PTIJ answers. If I inadvertently offend, flag for deletion.

I know that you're Chaba"d. Chaba"d is known for *kiruv*, and, personally, I think they do an amazing job at this.

One common form of *kiruv* is inviting non-practicing Jews to their home for a Shabbat meal (incidentally, this phrase that you cited is said before every Kiddush, not just the Friday night one. But, we'll use your citing as an example for any Kiddush.)

Here's the problem. Many of these Jews somewhat know that you make a bracha on food or drink, and then you immediately consume the food. What they **don't** know, is that Kiddush is an exception to that rule. So, (and tell me that you've **never** seen this happen!) when you make the bracha, they immediately start drinking the wine, because they don't know that you're supposed to wait until the end of the Kiddush.

Well, what else would you call such people? **morons**! Sometimes, you just have to tell people exactly what they are for them to get the idea and correct their mistake. This is not insulting or *lashon hara*. Call it "friendly rebuke".

Kudos to you and all Chabadniks for having such patience dealing with a few morons each Shabbat. I know that I couldn't do it.

**Postscript** I've used Chaba"d as an example. See my comments as to why. However, the reasoning applies to anyone who acts this way who is at a non-Chabad table as well. If you act this way, welcome to the moron's club. You're not alone, but you're in good hands. You can address questions as to why Chaba"d loves these morons so much to the OP.

Comment: So what about the rest of us? Or the rest of those at the Chabadniks’ table?

Comment: @DonielF OK, OK, fine ... you want to be a moron too?? Go ahead! I'm not stopping you, you **moron** :-) I'll have you in mind, tonight, *bli neder*.

Comment: @DanF +1, but a problem with your answer: I now know why Chabad says it. But what about everyone else? (Granted, I think others say "savri moronon v'rabonon v'rabosai," whereas Chabad only says "savri moronon," presumably because of the disproportionate number of mekruvim at their table)

Comment: @DanF I assure you that I am one of the morons.

Comment: @SAH "Moron is what moron does" (adapted from Forest Gump). I would give you a moronic answer, but, alas, that would make me a moron, too, which I'm not, b/c I posted this answer. My answer was, of course, not limited to Chabaniks. It's just that Chabadniks, perhaps, have greater patience dealing with these morons than non-Chabadniks do, from what I've seen. So, I don't think you're a moron. But, hey, if you feel like joining DonielF, I can't stop you. I'll have you in mind, tonight, also, bli neder. You're making my family jealous :-)

Comment: @DanF Please have me in mind during both kiddushes, and parashas zochor as well